# Equivalent definition of a locally integrable function II

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I need to demonstrate the equivalence of the following definitions:

**Def. 1**: We call a function $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}$ locally integrable iff for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ there exists an open neighbourhood of $x$ on which $f$ is absolutely integrable.

**Def. 2**: We call $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}$ locally integrable iff for every radius $r>0$ we have $\int_{B(0,r)} |f| \ \mathrm{d}m < \infty$.

Obviously, I am having a trouble with $1 \implies 2$.

**My attempts** I have tried the following, but it did not take me anywhere.

(1) I have tried assembling $B(0,r) = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B(x_n,r_n)$ as a union of open balls, but the local integrability does not guarantee that $f$ will be absolutely integrable on the whole radius $r_n$ for each $x_n$.

(2) Another thing I have tried is to pick some $x_1 \in B(0,r)$ and find a ball $B(x_1,r_1)\cap B(0,r)$ on which $f$ is integrable, and to continue similarly with $n=2,\ldots$, i.e., each time picking $x_n \in B(0,r) / \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B(x_i,r_i)$ using the choice, and then taking a ball $B(x_n,r_n)\cap B(0,r)$ around this point since it was not covered previously. However, the resulting union $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B(x_n,r_n) \cap B(0,r)$ is not guaranteed to cover the whole $B(0,r)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show that Definition 1 implies $f$ is absolutely integrable on every compact set.

Comment: Oh I see, for each $x\in K$, $K$ compact, we find an open neighbourhood by assumption, and then take only a finite number of these open neighbourhoods (i.e. those which cover $K$ completely). Thanks a lot, wouldn't be able to come up with this myself.

Comment: You're welcome.